# symfonys url_for not includes app index file in generated links

Tags: symfony1, routes

I generated new app for my symfony project with name 'admin'. Everything works fine, except one thing:

When i launch app by admin_dev.php, there are no problems, however, doing it by admin.php, makes all links pointing to frontend app, because 'admin.php' is not being added do link.

f.e., url_for function genarates:

> localhost/module

instead of:

> localhost/admin.php/module

Where and what i did wrong? Its not my first project, many times i was generating backend applications, but that problem i meet first time.

I have no idea what failed. Routing file is standard, untouched.

**EDIT:**
admin.php content:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('admin', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that admin.php will run your application in prod environment. If it is the case the default setting for prod environment is `no_script_name: true`. So change your settings.yml to read:

```
...
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         false
...
```

Comment: @WombaT did you clear your cache after making config changes?

Comment: Please check the cache to make sure it's read and cached correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what can goes wrong in your configuration. Verify you have set `no_script_name: false` in /apps/admin/config/settings.yml and there is no similar instruction in this file. Verify your cache directory is empty. It should work!